# Интерактивный ping

Tags: python, django

Как организовать ping интерактивно? Мой вариант тоже работает, но необходимо подождать...

```
def pings(request, phost):
  a = subprocess.Popen('ping -n -c 3 -W 2 %s' %phost,shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   res = a.stdout.readlines()
   return render_to_response('switch/pingf.html',{'p':res})
```

Answer (score 1):

У Django с этим не очень. Она умеет, конечно [выплевывать ответ постепенно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922874/how-to-stream-an-httpresponse-with-django), но там куча подводных камней.

Когда я выводил в браузер логи для саппорта (этакий аналог `tail -f`), я сделал сбоку отдельный веб-сервер (конкретно в моем случае — на, простите за неприличное, Node.js, но можно на Tornado, Twisted или Erlang), который работал с [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), а Django отдавало только страничку с коннектящимся туда JavaScript'ом. Возможно, такой вариант будет легче. А возможно и нет.